# A function $f(x)$ is such that, $f(x+ \frac{\pi}{2}) = \frac{\pi}{2} - |x|$ for all $x$. Find $f ' (\frac{\pi}{2})$.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I thought of going by finding derivative of the given expression. But that wouldn't be done as |x| is not differentiable . And even tried with the conventional derivative method, but not getting. Please help me out.

Comment: $f'(\frac {\pi} 2)$ does not exist.

Comment: Well I think the idea is to, first, see that $f(\frac{\pi}{2}) = \frac{\pi}{2}$. Now take the **definition** of derivative (the limit of difference ... )

Answer (score 0):

By the definition of derivative, we have
$$
f'(\pi/2)= \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(\pi/2+x)-f(\pi/2)}{x} = 
\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\pi/2-|x| -\pi/2}{x}=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{-|x|}{x}
$$
which doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

$|x|$ has not a differentiable only at $x=0$. However, we can compute the derivatives on left and right of 0.
Therefore, the derivative of $f$ at $\pi/2$ is 1 on the left and -1 on the right.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1375711)

Comment: How is my answer is not relevant to the question?

Comment: Writing down only the final result seems not to be an answer. You should show your calculations.

Comment: @Jan, I added some details, I couldn't see what my answer was lacking.